# Why PHPMailer can overwrite "setFrom" but not System.Net.Mail of .Net?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtpclient

When I use PHPMailer with gmail to send mail, I can specify the "setFrom" by something I want.
Let's say `$mail->setFrom('blabla@anywhat.com', 'blabla name')`.

So when I receive the mail, I see that the sender is 'blabla@anywhat.com'

But when I use System.Net.Mail of .Net with the same gmail account, I receive the mail sent by the google account.
Here is my C# source code:

```
using System.Net.Mail;

try
{

    // code removed as not relevent

    objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); /// Server IP
    objSMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("somegoogleaccount@gmail.com", "password");
    objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    objSmtpClient.Credentials = objSMTPUserInfo;    
    objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress('blabla@anywhat.com', 'blabla name');

    objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessage);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

So my question is, "Why PHPMailer can achieve this but not System.Net.Mail ?"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given that, spamers can easily send spam via PHPMailer. So .Net is more secure

Answer (score 0):

You can ask PHPMailer to do this, because it’s perfectly valid to do so, but that does not mean that the resulting messages will be accepted. Gmail will not allow you to use arbitrary from addresses. Doing this is generally a bad idea because it will cause your messages to fail SPF and DMARC checks, so don’t do it.